# Compare ACF date field (if exists) and post date and order DESC

Tags: custom-field, loop, query, sort, datepicker

I have an ACF date field (same format as post date) and in my Query I want it to be compared to the publish date of the post:

- If erstelldatum is not empty use erstelldatum for order
- If erstelldatum is empty use publish date for order instead
- Order descending

My code is working so far but the order isn`t right. It lists all posts with erstelldatum first followed by those without. I want them to be ordered descending by the above logic.

Also the posts without the ACF field are ordered in a strange way... descending down to 2010 followed by a sudden 2021 and descending from it again.

Help is highly appreciated!

````
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { // 'page' is used instead of 'paged' on Static Front Page
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}
  
$custom_query_args = array(
    'post_type'     => array( 'post' ),
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'orderby'       => array( 'erstelldatum' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC' ),
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'erstelldatum',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'erstelldatum',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            )
        )

    ),
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );```
````